# How to make multiple HttpRequests with pagination cursors in Parse Cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I want to make a HTTP GET request from a url and it will contain the url of next webpage. I have to continue this process till I get an empty "next" url.

My code is as follows:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("myFunc", fucntion (request, response){

    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
      url: fb_url
    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
       next_url = httpResponse.data.next_url;
       /******************/
       // code to make another HttpRequest with next_url and iteratively 
       // doing it till next_url is null

        response.success(httpResponse.text);   

    }, function(httpResponse) {
        response.error("error " + httpResponse); 
    }
});
```

I tried a lot of different ways, but all in vain. Can anyone tell me how can I make another HttpRequest with the next_url and keep doing it until next_url is null.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the http invocation in a function that can be called recursively.  This will return a chain of promises that make the requests until null is returned.

```
function keepGetting(url) {
    return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url:url }).then(function(httpResponse) {
        nextUrl = httpResponse.data.nextUrl;
        return (nextUrl === null)? httpResponse : keepGetting(nextUrl);
    });
}

Parse.Cloud.define("myFunc", fucntion (request, response){
    // initialize fb_url somehow
    keepGetting(fb_url).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);   
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error); 
    });
});
```

(Careful, if the service takes too long or returns too many results before null, your parse call will timeout)